# Do Zombie Sieges happen in other dimensions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a vilage in the End, and populated it with a few villagers, and I'd like to raise its population. I looked up on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_siege), but it contained to information about Zombie Sieges happening in other dimensions.
**So, do Zombie Sieges happen in the End and the Nether?**

Answer (score 1):

> At midnight each night (18000 in Minecraft time), there is a 10% chance that a zombie siege will be attempted that night. If a siege is to occur, attempts will be made each tick to start the siege until either a siege is successfully started, or the sun rises. Specifically, the siege attempt is abandoned when the sky light level reaches 12; however, inclement weather can allow siege start attempts to continue well past dawn, since it reduces the sky light level.

I would think that since zombies cannot spawn in the end or nether naturally that the 10% chance would never happen because there is already a 0% chance of zombies naturally spawning in the end and nether, although I did not find anywhere that it said they couldn't spawn so I would just test arround with it and see what happens.

Plus I believe you can test to see if your village actually counts as a valid village by just saying

> /locate Village

That should if your in nether or end if your village counts locate your village.

Comment: I already know that it counts as one, because my villagers bred. It's only possible in a valid village. And by the way, I can't use commands since I'm on Hardcore Mode.

Comment: TL;DR: Zombies only spawn in the overworld. Therefore: no zombies? No problem.